# settext not showing the fetched data from firebase realtime database android studio java

Tags: java, android, firebase

Login Page

```
package com.sheshagroups.satech.demoapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Objects;

public class C1A_JPS_Login extends AppCompatActivity {



    EditText StudentId, StudentPassword;
    TextView class_section;
    Button Login;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,sharedPreferences1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c1a_jps_login);

        StudentId = findViewById(R.id.studentid1a);
        StudentPassword = findViewById(R.id.studentpassword1a);
        Login = findViewById(R.id.loginC1A);
        class_section = findViewById(R.id.class_section);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!validateStudentPass() | !validateStudentId()){

                }else{
                    checkStudent();
                }
            }
        });

        class_section.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                Intent login = new Intent(C1A_JPS_Login.this, LoginPage.class);
                startActivity(login);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public Boolean validateStudentId(){
        String val = StudentId.getText().toString();
        if (val.isEmpty()){
            StudentId.setError("StudentId can't be Empty");
            return false;
        } else{
            StudentId.setError(null);
            return true;
        }}

    public Boolean validateStudentPass(){
        String val = StudentPassword.getText().toString();
        if (val.isEmpty()){
            StudentPassword.setError("Password can't be Empty");
            return false;
        } else{
            StudentPassword.setError(null);
            return true;
        }}


    public void checkStudent(){
        String studentid = StudentId.getText().toString().trim();
        String studentpass = StudentPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Class 1A");
        Query checkUserDatabase = reference.orderByChild("sstudentid").equalTo(studentid);

        checkUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    StudentPassword.setError(null);
                    String passwordFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(studentid).child("sstudentpass").getValue(String.class);
                    if(!Objects.equals(passwordFromDB,studentpass)){
                        StudentPassword.setError(null);
                        String nameFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("sname").getValue(String.class);
                        String classFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("sclass").getValue(String.class);
                        String sectionFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("ssection").getValue(String.class);
                        String studentidFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("sstudentid").getValue(String.class);
                        String rollnoFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("srollno").getValue(String.class);
                        String fnameFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("sfname").getValue(String.class);
                        String mnameFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("smname").getValue(String.class);
                        String mobileFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("smobile").getValue(String.class);
                        String addressFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("saddress").getValue(String.class);
                        String feeFromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("sfee").getValue(String.class);
                        Intent ihome = new Intent(C1A_JPS_Login.this,C1A_StudentDetail.class);
                        ihome.putExtra("name",nameFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("class",classFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("section",sectionFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("studentid",studentidFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("rollno",rollnoFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("fname",fnameFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("mname",mnameFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("mobile",mobileFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("address",addressFromDatabase);
                        ihome.putExtra("fee",feeFromDatabase);
                        startActivity(ihome);
                        finish();

                    }else{
                        StudentPassword.setError("Invalid Credentials");
                        StudentPassword.requestFocus();
                    }
                } else{
                    StudentId.setError("User does not exist");
                    StudentId.requestFocus();
                }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null){
            Intent home = new Intent(C1A_JPS_Login.this,C1A_Home.class);
            home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(home);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Profile Page

```
package com.sheshagroups.satech.demoapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class C1A_StudentDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView name,Class,section,rollno,studentid,fname,mname,mobile,address,fee;
    CardView homecard;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c1_astudent_detail);

        name=findViewById(R.id.studentname);
        Class=findViewById(R.id.studentclass);
        section=findViewById(R.id.studentsection);
        rollno=findViewById(R.id.studentrollno);
        studentid=findViewById(R.id.studentid);
        fname=findViewById(R.id.studentfname);
        mname=findViewById(R.id.studentmname);
        mobile=findViewById(R.id.studentmobile);
        address=findViewById(R.id.studentaddress);
        fee=findViewById(R.id.studentfee);
        homecard=findViewById(R.id.homecard);
        showStudentData();
        homecard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent back = new Intent(C1A_StudentDetail.this,C1A_Home.class);
                startActivity(back);
            }
        });


    }
    public void showStudentData(){

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String sname = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String sclass = intent.getStringExtra("class");
        String ssection = intent.getStringExtra("section");
        String srollno = intent.getStringExtra("rollno");
        String sstudentid = intent.getStringExtra("studentid");
        String sfname = intent.getStringExtra("fname");
        String smname = intent.getStringExtra("mname");
        String smobile = intent.getStringExtra("mobile");
        String sfee = intent.getStringExtra("fee");
        String saddress = intent.getStringExtra("address");
        name.setText(sname);
        Class.setText(sclass);
        section.setText(ssection);
        rollno.setText(srollno);
        studentid.setText(sstudentid);
        fname.setText(sfname);
        mname.setText(smname);
        mobile.setText(smobile);
        fee.setText(sfee);
        address.setText(saddress);
    }
}
```

Profile Layout Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".C1A_StudentDetail">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Student Detail"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/purple"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentname"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentclass"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Section"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentsection"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Id"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentid"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Roll No."
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentrollno"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Father's Name"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentfname"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mother Name"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentmname"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mobile No."
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentmobile"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Adddress"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentaddress"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fees"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Student Name"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentfee"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/homecard">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_home_24"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Go to Home"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/purple"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Model Class

```
package com.sheshagroups.satech.demoapp;

public class HelperClass1 {

    String Sname, Sclass, Ssection, Srollno, Sfname, Smname, Smobile, Sfee, Saddress,Sstudentid,Sstudentpass,SstudentTeacherID,SstudentTeacherPassword,SAttendance;

    public String getSname() {
        return Sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        Sname = sname;
    }

    public String getSclass() {
        return Sclass;
    }

    public void setSclass(String sclass) {
        Sclass = sclass;
    }

    public String getSsection() {
        return Ssection;
    }

    public void setSsection(String ssection) {
        Ssection = ssection;
    }

    public String getSrollno() {
        return Srollno;
    }

    public void setSrollno(String srollno) {
        Srollno = srollno;
    }

    public String getSfname() {
        return Sfname;
    }

    public void setSfname(String sfname) {
        Sfname = sfname;
    }

    public String getSmname() {
        return Smname;
    }

    public void setSmname(String smname) {
        Smname = smname;
    }

    public String getSmobile() {
        return Smobile;
    }

    public void setSmobile(String smobile) {
        Smobile = smobile;
    }

    public String getSfee() {
        return Sfee;
    }

    public void setSfee(String sfee) {
        Sfee = sfee;
    }

    public String getSaddress() {
        return Saddress;
    }

    public void setSaddress(String saddress) {
        Saddress = saddress;
    }
    public String getSstudentid() {
        return Sstudentid;
    }
    public void setSstudentid(String sstudentid) {
        Sstudentid = sstudentid;
    }

    public String getSstudentpass() {
        return Sstudentpass;
    }
    public void setSstudentpass(String sstudentpass) {
        Sstudentpass = sstudentpass;
    }

    public String getSstudentTeacherID() {
        return SstudentTeacherID;
    }

    public void setSstudentTeacherID(String sstudentTeacherID) {
        SstudentTeacherID = sstudentTeacherID;
    }

    public String getSstudentTeacherPassword() {
        return SstudentTeacherPassword;
    }

    public void setSstudentTeacherPassword(String sstudentTeacherPassword) {
        SstudentTeacherPassword = sstudentTeacherPassword;
    }

    public String getSAttendance() {
        return SAttendance;
    }

    public void setSAttendance(String SAttendance) {
        this.SAttendance = SAttendance;
    }

    public HelperClass1(String sname, String sclass, String ssection, String srollno, String sfname, String smname, String smobile, String sfee, String saddress, String sstudentid, String sstudentpass, String sstudentTeacherID, String sstudentTeacherPassword, String sattendance) {
        Sname = sname;
        Sclass = sclass;
        Ssection = ssection;
        Srollno = srollno;
        Sfname = sfname;
        Smname = smname;
        Smobile = smobile;
        Sfee = sfee;
        Saddress = saddress;
        Sstudentid = sstudentid;
        Sstudentpass = sstudentpass;
        SstudentTeacherID = sstudentTeacherID;
        SstudentTeacherPassword = sstudentTeacherPassword;
        SAttendance = sattendance;
    }
}
```

I am try to display the user data from the firebase realtime database to the profile page and trying to set the text but I am not able to do that. When in settext from database it is not visible in the textview. Please help me to fix my problem I will be highly thankfull to all of you please

Comment: You are trying fetching data in login screen and send data to profile screen via intent right? Have you checked with debugger whether the data is received from API is not null or empty? If it was good then debug in Profile screen whether the data is received via intent. Check whether the data received from loginscreen  is not null or empty

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).